# How can I create a hash url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am having a product controller which allows me to access the show method in the usual rails way

```
product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                 products#show
```

Now, I would like to have a unique hash url for each product, which can be accessed at the root path e.g.
    mydomain.com/24fe3455g

What would be the best way to do this?

Best
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to define a matching route in your `routes.rb`. Since it kind of a "fall through" you would usually put it at the end of the routes. have a look at the guides for how to define that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

if you want to always use this hash-style urls throughout your application instead of ids, you would also implement `to_param` and `self.from_param` methods in your model: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

you could also use a gem like friendly_id if you like some tool support: http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/Guide.rdoc

Comment: the recommended gem is nice, but i expect to have many products. so it might be happening that  i ll have multiple items with the same name, so this would kind of restrict the use of this gem..

Answer (score 0):

you could store an `md5` in the DB for each row - compute this md5 for `id+timestamp` for example (as concatenated strings), then have your route like:

```
product GET    /products/:hash(.:format)                 products#show
```

You could also use a [`UUID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for generatind unique id's